# Writing an API to Interact with my own custom hardware?

Tags: api, operating-system, kernel, linux-device-driver, systems-programming

Suppose I've a custom made hardware which is connected to the computer. I've my drivers installed to communicate with the hardware.Then how can I write an API through which i can access my hardware programmatically(As an example consider accessing oculus rift head mounted device using OculusSDK).Specifically how do i make my API communicate with device drivers to access the hardware using system call interface? If possible explain with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware driver should implement a way of interracting with user.

E.g., it can be special file(s), which user can open (using standard `open(2)`) and then call `read`/`write`/`mmap`/`ioctl` for it. Each such operation actually triggers some driver code, which in case triggers some hardware request.